# String.find() words containing wildcards

Tags: lua

i have a few strings that use the wildcard "-" instead of a space, and, i'm having a hard time in figuring out how to handle those wildcards (first time doing string manipulation in lua)

here's what i've got:

```
string_A = "this-is-a-word"

string_array =
{
    line_A = "this-is-a-word-but-bigger"
    line_B = "this-is-a-bigger-word"
}

for _, string_line in pairs(string_array) do
    if string.find(string_line, string_A) then
    ...
end
```

Each argument should behave like a single word, which means that the only match would be string_A/line_A as it contains the same block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-` is one of the magic characters `^$()%.[]*+-?)` in string [patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1). Having them in the string you're looking for will cause problems.

You have two options.

#### A

search for the plain string using [string.find](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.find)'s optional fourth parameter. This will not treat any character as magical.

```
string.find(string_lineA, stringA, 1, true)
```

or short

```
string_lineA:find(stringA, 1, true)
```

#### B

escape any magic character using `%`

```
string.find(string_line, "this%-is%-a%-word")
```

From the manual:

> **%x**: (where x is any non-alphanumeric character) represents the
> character x. This is the standard way to escape the magic characters.
> Any non-alphanumeric character (including all punctuation characters,
> even the non-magical) can be preceded by a '%' to represent itself in
> a pattern.

If we can do this for any non-alphanumeric character we can escape any magical characters by preceeding any non-alphanumeric character with `%`. `%w` matches alphanumeric characters. Capital letter negates the character class so `%W` is non-alphanumeric. Which leads us to

```
string.gsub(yourPattern, "%W", "%%%0")
```

or short

```
yourPattern:gsub("%W, "%%%0")
```

where `%%` is the escaped `%` and `%0` is the matched string.

Comment: Yes, i did read the docs about the magic characters and what they do, but i couldn't find any practical examples on how to use the syntax properly for this specific situation, thanks for the snippets and the explanation, solution A would be best in this case as the strings do come from other functions and for loops so escaping the magic characters would be very impractical

Comment: if you're just using string.find option a is the simplest. other functions do not have that plain match parameter.

Comment: [...] A third, optional numeric argument `init` specifies where to start the search; its default value is `1` and can be negative. A `true` as a fourth, optional argument plain turns off the pattern matching facilities [...]


There it is the working code:

`string.find(string_line, string_A, 1, true)`


EDIT: Does `1` identify the first character of the string?

Comment: sorry my fault, fixed it. I'm just used to using the short syntax where it is the third argument. but it is the functions fourth parameter of course. 1 specifies that the search shall begin at character 1.